# How to remove "Click for help about adding basic HTML formatting"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, custom-form, list-form

I have SharePoint 2013 Enterprise. In one of the Custom lists, specifically in 2 Number fields, this sentence appeared:
**"Click for help about adding basic HTML formatting"**
It's nor easy for my users to use the form in such way. I've searched over and found out a few tricks also to open the form in another browser like explorer.
Please let me know if you had experience how to remove the sentence from fields.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Add script editor webpart and add the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">
   span.ms-formdescription
   { display: none }
</style> ​
```